# Why ajax call give error of Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, multithreading, twitter-bootstrap

I am doing assignment in ASP.net MVC5. When i do ajax call it successffully go to action method(debugged). But after that when i make markup of something it and append to the body it give the error in jquery min.js and the error on console is :
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. 
jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: $document is not defined

My code is below:

```
$.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            success: function (data, status) {
                if (status && data) {
                    var Markup = data;
                    var Title = Id && Id != null ? "edit" : "New";
                    $AddEdit = BootstrapModal.createAndShow("modal", Title, Markup); // this is another method in JS
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("not workig");
            }
        });
```

Bootstrap method is:

```
var createAndShow = function (ElementId, Title, Markup) {
        debugger;

      //Here some markup is creating and append to body

        $("body").append(Markup); //Here error come
```

Comment: `Why ajax call give error of Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated?` - because synchronous XMLHttpRequest is deprecated in every modern browser

Comment: your other error `$document is not defined` - as the code you posted doesn't refer to $document anywhere, then I'd say that error is in code you have not posted

Comment: Jaomanda you are right. document ready was missing.

Comment: `async: false` should never be used. remove it and your error will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are facing: 
"Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user’s experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/"

says it all. You are using a synchronous Ajax Call, by setting it explicitly in this line:

```
async: false,
```

This is deprecated. If applicable, change it to true. There are however very rare cases, where a synchronous ajax call might be useful.